# Copy elements using xsl:copy-of without attributes

Tags: attributes, xslt-1.0

I have a xml like shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schools>
   <city>Marshall</city>
   <state>Maryland</state>
   <highschool>
   <schoolname>Marshalls</schoolname>
   <department id="1">
     <deptCode seq="1">D1</deptCode>
     <deptName seq="2">Chemistry</deptName>
     <deptHead seq="3">Henry Carl</deptHead>
     <deptRank seq="4">L</deptRank>
   </department>
   <department id="2">
    ..
    ..
    ..
   </highschool>
   </schools>
```

In XSL i am copying the contents from department based on deptCode using

```
  <xsl:copy-of select="*">
```

This produces result with all the attributes in the element tags.
 Is it possible to ignore the attributes while using xsl:copy-of?

The desired result is like shown below

```
     <deptCode>D1</deptCode>
     <deptName>Chemistry</deptName>
     <deptHead>Henry Carl</deptHead>
     <deptRank>L</deptRank>
```

xsl:valueOf is working as required but i am trying to know if it 
 can be done with in xsl:copy-of?  As a note, in my requirement, there are nearly 5 or 6 attributes for each element.  Can someone please help? Thanks in Advance..

regards
Udayakiran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> xsl:valueOf is working as required but i am trying to know if it can
>   be done with in xsl:copy-of?

No. `xsl:copy-of` is a package deal, you cannot pick and choose. To avoid repetitive coding, use a template matching `department/*`.